# Freertos priority

Tags: multitasking, freertos, zynq

I am trying to implement freeRTOS with 3 tasks.

1. write to an address x
2. read the written data from address x
3. blink an led

Without task 3, I have implemented the read and write tasks alone by assigning a higher priority to read task and it works well. But when I assign the led task(task 3) with lowermost priority my led blinks and write and read tasks do not work properly.

Can anyone explain the reason for this?

Also, I would like to perform the write-read tasks in parallel with the led task (with same priority).

Please help me out to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided is very less and incomplete so there can be numerous problems. I am learning FreeRTOS so I am not an expert. In my opinion, I feel that the data at address x is getting corrupted (due to pre-emption of tasks) that's why write and read tasks are not working properly. You either need to implement *Mutex* or *binary semaphore* for mutual exclusion of address x .

**NOTE:** there no such thing called *parallel execution* in freeRTOS.

Try giving the same priority to all three tasks with mutual exclusion

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information.

Firstly for 1 and 2 tasks you need to use mutex to share resource between tasks.[FreeRTOS Mutexes](https://www.freertos.org/Real-time-embedded-RTOS-mutexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since Task 2 relies on Task 1, you can set them as equal priority and have Task 1 flag Task 2 when it is done. Task 2 can wait indefinitely until the flag from Task 1 is set.

Regarding Task 3, is the LED running on an interval? Or does it also depend on Task 1 or 2? Usually you can set the LED to a lower priority and since it has more time during its on and off, Tasks 1 and 2 should not be affected.

Maybe you are delaying the LED using hardware delays and not Task delays? This could affect performance.